# Is this topological sort in Ruby flawed?

Tags: ruby, topological-sort

I was looking at topological sorting and it seemed very complicated.  I came up with this and it seems to work with all the examples i could find.  Is this logic flawed?

```
@tsort_array = []
def tsort item, dependencies_array
  if index = @tsort_array.index(item)
    @tsort_array = @tsort_array.insert(index, dependencies_array).flatten
  else
    @tsort_array += dependencies_array
    @tsort_array << item
  end

  @tsort_array = @tsort_array.uniq
end
```

Using the example from http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tsort/rdoc/TSort.html has the same results.

```
>> tsort 1, [2,3]
=> [2, 3, 1]
>> tsort 2, [3]
=> [3, 2, 1]
>> tsort 3, []
=> [3, 2, 1]
>> tsort 4, []
=> [3, 2, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting idea, but unfortunately the algorithm has some flaws.

First, let us summarize the algorithm, to ensure we have a common understanding: There is a global array `tsort_array`. The method `tsort` takes as input a vertex `item` and an array `dependencies_array` holding the dependencies of `item` (meaning the vertices that have to come before the vertex `item` in the topological ordering). The method will then check if `item` already exists in `tsort_array`. If so, the dependencies of `item` will be inserted directly before `item`. If not, the dependencies are appended to the end of `tsort_array` and `item` is appended after that. Finally, `tsort_array` is scanned for duplicates, retaining only the first occurrence of each vertex. After each call to `tsort`, the topological order of the graph added so far is supposed to be contained in `tsort_array`.

The algorithm will work correctly if every added `item` has not been added to `tsort_array` so far (meaning every call to `tsort` hits the `else` case). However, this requires adding the vertices in topological order (i.e. no previously added vertex has a dependency on the current `item`). So you would already have to know the topological order to add the vertices in this way.

The algorithm will behave incorrectly in the following scenarios:

- The algorithm does not detect cycles:

  [image: Example 1: Cyclic graph]

  ```
  > tsort 2, [1]
  => [1, 2]
  > tsort 3, [2]
  => [1, 2, 3]
  > tsort 1, [3]
  => [3, 1, 2]
  ```

  This is of course not a valid topological ordering, but the algorithm does not indicate any errors. This is fine if it is assumed that the input graphs for the algorithm will always be acyclic.
- The algorithm does not behave correctly if the dependencies of a vertex are added incrementally:

  [image]

  ```
   tsort 1, []
   => [1]
   tsort 3, [2]
   => [1, 2, 3]
   tsort 1, [3]
   => [3, 1, 2]
  ```

  The example initially adds `1` with no dependencies. Then `3` is added with a dependency on `2`. These two vertices will be inserted after `1`. Finally, `1` is updated with a dependency for `3`. This will move `3` before `1`, and therefore before its dependency on `2`.

  This is fine if it is assumed that no such updates will occur, i.e. the dependencies of a vertex will always be specified in one call to `tsort`.
- The following example is sorted incorrectly:

  [image]

  ```
  > tsort 4, [2,3]
  => [2, 3, 4]
  > tsort 3, [1]
  => [2, 1, 3, 4]
  > tsort 2, [3]
  => [3, 2, 1, 4]
  ```

  By specifying the dependencies of `4` in the order `2,3` and then adding the dependency `1 -> 3`, the vertex `1` will be inserted in between `2` and `3`, so after `2` and before `3`. Therefore, `2` is at the beginning of the list after this step. Finally, adding the dependency `3 -> 2` will place `3` before `2`. Therefore, `3` will be at the beginning of the list, so before its dependency on `1`.